# How to build gstreamer ugly plugins from source

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

I would like to change some code in one element X in gstreamer ugly plugin and rebuild and use it.

How I can do it?

I have gstreamer-0.10  and installed gstreamer-ugly plugin.
I would like to download only gstreamer0-10 ugly plugin code and change it and would like to use the new lib file. How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately gstreamer-ugly depends on a lot of stuff in at least libgstreamer and plugins-base (if you're using linux and your distro provides *-dev packages as debian/ubuntu does).

If you're on debian you could use dpkg-buildpackage after checking out the source using apt-source. The big advantage here is that all the build dependencies can be easily installed.

The manual way will probably need you to first build all the other gstreamer packages have a close look on what ./configure tells you
I'm workin on debian and have already built gstreamer+plugins to backport the recent ones to ubuntu (although I'm not sure if I did it in a best-practice way ;) )

**/edit**: I'll try to cover the basic steps for ubuntu here:

- add the source repositories to apt (check the "source code" checkbox in the [ubuntu software center's "software sources" tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Software_Tab)
- `sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev devscripts`
- `sudo apt-get build-dep gst-plugins-ugly0.10`
- `apt-get source gst-plugins-ugly0.10`
- change to the newly created gst-plugins-base* folder
- `dpkg-buildpackage` (and make sure it works)
- change the source to your needs
- you can rebuild it any time using dpkg-buildpackage (to simply see if it compiles `make` might be faster though). This creates a .deb file in the parent folder that you can simply install using `dpkg -i`
- If it's a useful change you might want to get in touch with the gstreamer-devs ;)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 11.10...Could you please mention the steps including src download to environment variable set?

Comment: @StackReader I've updated the post to provide a brief step-by-step guide

Comment: Thanks for the steps. But, from which repository I will download the dpkg-buildpackage? when I am doing "sudo apt-get install dpkg-buildpackage devscripts" it is saying dpkg-buildpackage package not found...

Comment: What is the meaning of the 1st step "add the source repositories to apt"?

Answer (score 0):

On a debian system, run apt-get build-dep gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly to get all the build dependencies for that package. After that you can build the package from git, source tarball or even rebuild the debian package (using dkgp-buildpackage).